# Pull Facebook Page / Place "Topic" via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

In September 2012, Facebook introduced "place topics" as described here:

http://starien.com/facebook-pages/place-topics-on-facebook-pages/

"Topics" act as tags or subcategories for pages and places. These differ from the more generic "category" labels (eg. "local business") by adding a layer of specificity (eg. "liquor store"). Topics are found under the profile image next to a "tag" icon.

I'll use this page / place, with the topic "liquor store," as an example: http://www.facebook.com/RoyalLiquor

I'm looking for a way to pull these topics from Facebook pages. The Graph API for this location gives me a category of "Shopping/retail," and a handful of other information, but the topic "liquor store" is nowhere to be found.

Clicking on the "liquor store" topic brings you to what looks like a special topic page. So it looks like "liquor store" has a topic id of 199833073363963. Interestingly, when attempting to pull data about the topic via the Graph API, you get the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) App must be on whitelist", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 3
  }
}
```

This error appears even within the context of the Facebook Graph API Explorer app.

Is there any way to pull this topic data? Or is this simply a new feature for which Facebook has yet to introduce an API?

Thanks for any help! Google doesn't seem to have much information on the topic.

Comment: It probably does not have an API endpoint yet. This article http://www.technologyreview.com/featuredstory/428150/what-facebook-knows/ says Facebook gets most of this type of data from [Factual](http://Factual.com). You might want to start there.

Comment: Looks like that's the case. I actually ended up using the Foursquare API (also associated with Factual) to do what I needed to do. It sucks that I had to do an additional API call, but it got the job done.

Comment: @cpilko Factual does not mention Facebook in its customers (foursquare is listed). Also, a Facebook developer has [listed the categories](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=cfa41b33cdb24da3&resid=CFA41B33CDB24DA3%211162&parid=CFA41B33CDB24DA3%21215&authkey=%21AA-jFXnztM6D6gA) and you'll see it is quite different from those provided by Factual.

Comment: @rds: At the time I wrote this, Facebook *was* listed on the Factual website. Of course, tech is always in a state of flux, so FB may not still be using them, or may not be *admitting* they use them. Yes, I agree the categories are different on FB than factual, but using the Factual APIs, the OP could solve their question.