# How to get facebook Fanpages subcategories?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I need to getsubcategories from facebook fanpages.
With graph. I can get from from every single like, this infomations:

```
"data": [
      {
        "category": "Musician/band", 
        "name": "Paola Requena", 
        "id": "168432406524747", 
        "created_time": "2013-06-09T15:25:43+0000"
      },
```

"Id" is the fan page id, that returns me the following informations:

```
{
  "id": "168432406524747", 
  "app_id": "0", 
  "bio": "Tras haber sido recibida exitosamente en festivales prestigiosos como el Festival Internacional de Música Castell de Peralada, Festival Internacional de Música y Danza de Granada, Festival de Música y Danza de Úbeda, Certamen Internacional de guitarra de Barcelona, Ciclo Navidad con CajaMurcia, “Forum de las Culturas” de Barcelona, Sociedad Española de la guitarra de Madrid…Paola Requena se convierte en una de las guitarrístas españolas con más proyección de su generación.\n\nNacida en Cartagena (España), realiza sus estudios superiores de guitarra en la Ecole Normale de Musique “Alfred Cortot” de Paris con el profesor Alberto Ponce donde obtiene en 2003 el Diploma Superior de Ejecución por unanimidad del tribunal, y en el Conservatorio Superior “Oscar Esplá” de Alicante con Ignacio Rodes obteniendo en 2007 el Diploma de Profesor Superior de guitarra y el premio extraordinario fin de carrera.\n\nCompleta su formación en clases magistrales con los maestros: José Tomás, David Russell, Roberto Aussel, Jose Miguel Moreno, Ricardo Gallén…\n \nGalardonada en numerosos concursos internacionales de guitarra como el Concurso Internacional Francisco Tárrega de Benicassim, Printemps de la guitare de Charleroi (Bélgica), Certamen Internacional Andrés Segovia de la Herradura (Granada), Concurso Internacional “Comarca del Condado” Jaén, Concurso “José Tomás” de Almería, Concurso Permanente de Juventudes Musicales de España, Sociedad de Conciertos de Alicante, Concurso “Cincilia”…\n\nEn Enero de 2010 fue invitada por la Embajada de España en Austria para ofrecer dos recitales en Viena, uno en el Instituto Cervantes y otro en el Palacio Imperial “Hofburg” donde tocó para el Presidente de Austria Heinz Fischer y para los Embajadores de España con motivo de la inauguración de la Presidencia Española en la Unión Europea.\n\nHa actuado como solista con la Orquesta Sinfónica de Valencia, con el Collegium Instrumentale, con l’Orchestre de Chambre de Wallonie, con la Orquesta Sinfónica de Alicante… \n\nHa sido seleccionada por la Fundación A.I.E (Sociedad de Artistas, Intérpretes y Ejecutantes de España), para participar como solista en el ciclo “Clásicos en Ruta”. Actuando en ciudades como A Coruña, Cádiz, Pamplona, Mérida, Alcázar de San Juan…\n\nHa realizado grabaciones con la productora madrileña Eurodeltamusic que están siendo emitidas por TVE y Canal Sur.\n\nRecientemente ha sido galardonada en los “Premios Injuve para la Creación Jóven 2010” otorgados por el Instituto Nacional de la Juventud. Gracias a ello ha sido invitada a tocar en el Festival de Música de Segovia, organizado por la Fundación Juan de Borbón, y en el Círculo de Bellas Artes de Madrid.\n\n\n", 
  "can_post": true, 
  "category": "Musician/band", 
  "checkins": 0, 
  "genre": "Guitarra Clásica", 
  "has_added_app": false, 
  "is_community_page": false, 
  "is_published": true, 
  "likes": 782, 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Paola-Requena/168432406524747", 
  "name": "Paola Requena", 
  "talking_about_count": 10, 
  "website": "http://www.paolarequena.com\nhttp://www.youtube.com/user/paolarequena2", 
  "were_here_count": 0
}
```

i notice that the filed "subcategories" is not present. 
Is it possible to get Fan pages subcategories from facebook ?

Comment: a similar question was asked some time back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242313/pull-facebook-page-place-topic-via-graph-api they may still have not supported the api to get the subcategories yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with FQL with the following query:

select super_category_type, type from page where page_id = 168432406524747